# Mysql reduce execution time of query involving multiple tables and conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables namely `emp_table` , `project_table` , `dept_table` , and `team_table`. I am storing the ids of related project, department, and team in main table, i.e `emp_table`. I have written the following query to retrieve all the details.

```
SELECT
  a.emp_id ,
  a.emp_name,
  a.emp_manager,
  IF(a.emp_dept = 0,'',c.dept_name),
  IF(a.emp_project = 0,'',b.proj_name),
  IF(a.emp_team = 0,'',d.team_name)
FROM
  emp_table a,
  project_table b,
  dept_table c,
  team_table d
WHERE
  (CASE WHEN a.emp_project = 0 THEN 1=1 ELSE a.emp_project = b.proj_id  END)
  AND (CASE WHEN a.emp_dept = 0 THEN 1=1 ELSE a.emp_dept = c.dept_id END)
  AND (CASE WHEN a.emp_team = 0 THEN 1=1 ELSE a.emp_team = d.team_id END)
GROUP BY a.emp_id
ORDER BY emp_name
```

The table `emp_table` has close to 1000 rows. The rest of the tables are small(maximum 20 rows).
The query takes 6 seconds to execute. I want to improve the execution time. Please let me know how can I do this. Any advice for improvement would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a data sample from each table, and a sample result of what you want to achieve?  The use of old style implicit joins (comma-separated `FROM`) is confusing the issue here. Also unclear is the aim of the `GROUP BY` since there are no aggregates (`MAX(),MIN(),COUNT(),SUM()...`)

Comment: 1000 rows is _tiny_ in database terms, so certainly we may be able to improve this.  Set something up over at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I changed the old style joins to left joins as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the old style implicit joins (as a comma-separated `FROM` clause) makes your query attempt difficult to understand, but examining it I am thinking what you are looking for is actually a simple series of `LEFT JOIN`s against the 3 tables from `emp_table`.

Using the explicit `JOIN` syntax is both clearer to read, and eliminates the need for all those complex `CASE` statements and `IF`s.

I've also removed the `GROUP BY` since there are no aggregate functions being used. I replaced it with `DISTINCT` to de-duplicate rows.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  a.emp_id ,
  a.emp_name,
  a.emp_manager,
  /* Use COALESCE to convert NULLs to '' since the LEFT JOIN will return NULL */
  COALESCE(c.dept_name, '') AS dept_name,
  COALESCE(b.project_name, '') AS project_name,
  COALESCE(d.team_name, '') AS team_name
FROM
  emp_table a
  /* All joins are LEFT JOIN so non-matching will return NULL in the emp_table side */
  LEFT JOIN project_table b ON a.emp_project = b.proj_id
  LEFT JOIN dept_table c ON a.emp_dept = c.dept_id
  LEFT JOIN team_table d ON a.emp_team = d.team_id
ORDER BY emp_name
```

The success of these `LEFT JOIN`s as opposed to your `CASE` statements inspecting for zeros depends on *absence* of things like `dept_id = 0`. Assuming auto-incrementing IDs, that seems a safe bet.

Now, assuming you have properly defined `PRIMARY KEYS` on `proj_id, dept_id, team_id` and properly defined `FOREIGN KEYS` on the associated columns in `emp_table`, the performance should be excellent as MySQL will use all indexes available to it.

Your `emp_table` definition ought to look something like the following, adjusting of course for the correct data types and lengths...

```
CREATE TABLE emp_table
(
  emp_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  /* other columns, etc.. */
  /* Make sure these exactly match the types of the referenced table */
  emp_proj INT,
  emp_dept INT,
  emp_team INT,
  /* Defining these foreign keys will enforce indexing and vastly improve performance */
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_proj) REFERENCES project_table (proj_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_dept) REFERENCES dept_table (dept_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_team) REFERENCES team_table (team_id)
)
```

Comment: +1 you beat me to it. I am really surprised by the amount of people on SO that do not properly or at all use JOINS.